# EPSON L3151 won't connect to AP via WPS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer, epson-workforce

I have an EPSON L3151 printer. Recently my router has been changed (but to the exact same model, just different device because there was something wrong with the previous one).

I resetted the network settings on my printer by:

1. Turning it off
2. Turning it on while holding the network report button
3. Waiting till network status diodes stop blinking

Then I tried to connect to my new router via WPS by holding the Wi-Fi button for several seconds until network status diodes start blinking alternately. I also pressed and held the WPS button on my router until it gave me a signal that it's ready to connect via WPS. Unfortunately, after waiting for a minute network status on my diodes start blinking at once which, according to manual, means the connecting process has failed.

I've tried connecting to my router with different device and it worked without any problems, which suggests the problem is with the printer itself and not the router.

The printer works fine if I connect to it directly with a cable.

I can also connect to the printer via Wi-Fi direct with my smartphone.

How do I make the EPSON L3151 printer connect to my router or diagnose the problem?  I also searched for a way to reset my printer to factory settings but couldn't find a way to do it except resetting network settings - is there a way to do it?

Comment: I can't find the spec for the EPSON L3151, but is it possible that it only supports 2.4 GHz WiFi and the new router is set to 5GHz? Try setting the router to 2.4.

Comment: My router supports both 2.4 GhZ and 5 GhZ. So I switched it to support only 2.4 GhZ and tried connecting my printer via WPS but unfrotunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it working. I experimented more with my router and I noticed it has a "Smart Wi-Fi -> channel optimization" setting. I'm not exactly sure what it's doing but after turning it off I was able to connect to my router with my EPSON L3151 printer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).